# How to join dummy columns to main table?

Tags: python, pandas, dummy-variable

I am trying to create dummy variables for the categorical variables. However when I create them , I am getting 'ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified '. Here is the code:

```
dummy2 = pd.get_dummies(data['Teaching'], prefix='Teach')

dummy2.head ()
dummy2.columns = ['Small/Rural','Teaching']

data = data.join(dummy2)
##################
dummy3 = pd.get_dummies(data['Gender'], prefix='Gender_')

dummy3.head()
dummy3.columns = ['Male','Female']

data = data.join(dummy3)
#####################
dummy4 = pd.get_dummies(data['PositionTitle'], prefix='pos_')

dummy4.head()
dummy4.columns = ['Acting Director','RegioReresentative']

data = data.join(dummy4)
#####################


dummy5 = pd.get_dummies(data['Compensation'], prefix='COMP')

dummy5.head()
dummy5.columns = ['23987','46978','89473','248904']

data = data.join(dummy5)

#################3
dummy6 = pd.get_dummies(data['TypeControl'], prefix='Type')

dummy6.head()
dummy6.columns = ['City/country','District','Investor','Non Profit']

data = data.join(dummy6)
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of you dataframe ?

Answer (score 5):

There is a good explanation of how to do this using pd.concat found at
https://towardsdatascience.com/the-dummys-guide-to-creating-dummy-variables-f21faddb1d40. Modifying it for this example would look like the following:

```
dummy2 = pd.get_dummies(data['Teaching'], prefix='Teach')
data = pd.concat([data, dummy2], axis = 1)
```